# Azure App Service - Install .msi using Azure DevOps Pipeline or Kudu terminal

Tags: azure, powershell, libreoffice, permission-denied, azure-appservice

Need to install LibreOffice to my Azure App Service.

**1. Azure DevOps**

- I used powershell `Start-Process` to silent install but getting Permission denied.

```
Start-Process: /home/vsts/work/_temp/5cc8c99d-ed13-4b1b-823b-3cd9b56fdd1b.ps1:5
Line |
   5 |  Start-Process /home/vsts/work/1/s\LibreOffice_7.4.0_Win_x64.msi -Argu …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | An error occurred trying to start process
     | '/home/vsts/work/1/s/LibreOffice_7.4.0_Win_x64.msi' with
     | working directory '/home/vsts/work/1/s'. Permission denied
```

**2. Kudu terminal**

- Getting Access Denied error when trying to run `Start-Process` manually.

Are there any alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: What is your goal or what are you trying to achieve? You won’t be able to deploy the MSI on an Azure App Service as it is a sandbox environment without any access to the underlying OS functionality.

Comment: Not possible to install something on the host. The alternative is to use a docker container which has it already installed.

Comment: @Alex You should turn your comment into an answer

Comment: @CSharpRocks good point, done

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to install something on the host. The alternative is to use a docker container which has it already installed.

https://azure.github.io/AppService/windows-containers/

> App Service supports Windows Containers! Deploying your application in a Windows Container enables you to bring along dependencies such as custom fonts, cultures and GAC deployed assemblies. When deploying a containerized application, the Windows Container is an isolation and security boundary. As a result, calls to libraries that would normally be blocked by the Azure App Service will instead succeed when running inside of a Windows Container.